# KIVY TypeError: on_keyboard_down() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Now I'm attempting to make it so that instead of clicking to move the `PlayerImage` I want to use arrowkeys, I tried to implement left and right first but then when I tested it I got this:

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/acrobat/Desktop/dive/test.py", line 91, in <module>
     runTouchApp(root)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 403, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 370, in _mainloop
     self.modifiers):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/var/folders/42/pdwcpzkj0j56rssch8hjpwnm0000gn/T/pip-build-oh1mgzrd/kivy/kivy/_event.c:8119)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1224, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (/private/var/folders/42/pdwcpzkj0j56rssch8hjpwnm0000gn/T/pip-build-oh1mgzrd/kivy/kivy/_event.c:14008)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1148, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (/private/var/folders/42/pdwcpzkj0j56rssch8hjpwnm0000gn/T/pip-build-oh1mgzrd/kivy/kivy/_event.c:13537)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 159, in _on_window_key_down
     return self.dispatch('on_key_down', keycode, text, modifiers)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/var/folders/42/pdwcpzkj0j56rssch8hjpwnm0000gn/T/pip-build-oh1mgzrd/kivy/kivy/_event.c:8119)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1224, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (/private/var/folders/42/pdwcpzkj0j56rssch8hjpwnm0000gn/T/pip-build-oh1mgzrd/kivy/kivy/_event.c:14008)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1148, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (/private/var/folders/42/pdwcpzkj0j56rssch8hjpwnm0000gn/T/pip-build-oh1mgzrd/kivy/kivy/_event.c:13537)
 TypeError: on_keyboard_down() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

`PlayerImage` Class

```
class PlayerImage(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(PlayerImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.states = {"personred/rest.png/": 0,
                       "person.zip/": 1}
        self.currentstate = self.states["personred/rest.png/"]

        self.art = "./rpgArt/" + str(self.currentstate)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self,None)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)


    def on_keyboard_down(self, keycode): # KEYBOARD FUNC
        if keycode[1] == "right": 
            self.x += 10
        if keycode[1] == "left":
            self.x -= 10


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.currentstate = self.states["person.zip/"]
        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        angle = degrees(atan2(touch.y - self.center_y,
                              touch.x - self.center_x))

        Animation(center=touch.pos, angle=angle).start(self)
        self.currentstate = self.states["personred/rest.png/"]
```

My build:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<PlayerImage>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: self.angle
            axis: (0, 0, 1)
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
<PlayerImage2>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: self.angle
            axis: (0, 0, 1)
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
''')
```

Second Build:

```
root = Builder.load_string('''
    Widget:
        Widget:
            PlayerImage:
                source: './rpgArt/person.zip'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True

    ''')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace 'keycode' in your 'on_keyboard_down' method with '*args' and then do a print(*args') in the method you might get a clue about which 5 arguments are passed to the method.

Comment: Yes thank you, I had to add `text` `modifiers` etc... then I printed them!